# How to find and operate System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip item in external .Net application by item name?

Tags: c#

There is external .Net application (its code is unavailable) running in this machine and having a MenuStrip type main menu.

In `File/Connections` sub-menu exists sub item with name `XYZ`, its location is unknown.

I need to find and launch this menu item from inside my .Net application.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code that you're having trouble with, or are you just asking a general question, which will undoubtedly generate a lot of general answers?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx